# Did not file W-8BEN but received dividend income from US stocks and zero withholding tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, non-resident, withholding

I am an Indian citizen who worked in US for some time and returned in 2002 to India. I last filed a 1040NR return in 2002 and after that did not file 1040NR. I just realised that I have been receiving dividend income on my US stocks in my brokerage account but since I did not submit a W-8BEN, the withholding tax was 0.

So,

1. Most likely I owe dividend tax to US for all these past years. Is that correct?
2. How do I rectify this situation?  Can I file 1040NR for years from 2003 till 2014  and declare and pay the tax? The amount involved is not not much - I recd about $300 in dividend every year.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. If you don't have a W-8BEN on file, your brokerage account record-keeper may have had additional tax withholding (my firm withholds about 30%, IIRC). If that is the case, you may not have to. If that is not the case, you most likely will owe something, however small. Either way, you would want to reach out to your record keeper for the exact numbers and seek a tax advisor to get the documents in order.